# How to properly parse a multidimensional JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

JSFiddle providing exact duplication of errors: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g65wj1e7/5/)

I am trying to "step" through a multidimensional array. Each time that I try to load $.parseJSON() an error is thrown. I have already spent hours with Dr. Google looking for answers or hints. So, if this has been answered, please be gentle.

My JSON array that I am trying to step through was created by json_encode() of data posted by an AJAX function.

```
{
    "propertyType": "{"
    propertyType1 ":"
    Apartment Style Flat ","
    propertyType2 ":"
    Loft Style "}",
    "houseAge": "",
    "living_area": ""
}
```

AJAX Data that is being sent to PHP before being posted:
console.log(vals.advanced) produces

```
Object {
    propertyType: "{"
    propertyType1 ":"
    Apartment Style Flat ","
    propertyType2 ":"
    Loft Style "}",
    houseAge: "",
    living_area: ""
}
```

**EDIT:**
The Data arrays were created with the following code:

```
var checkboxes = [
    'propertyType'
];

// gather all checked check boxes and store in json array format for submission
$.each(
    checkboxes,
    function (i, e) {
        if(i==0) i=1; 
        var found = false;
        $("input[name=" + e + "]:checked").each(
            function () {
                id = this.name;
                arrCB[id + i++] = (this.value);
                found = true;
            }
        );
        if (found) {
            advanced[id] = JSON.stringify(arrCB);
            i = 1;
            arrCB = {}; // zero out holders
        }
    }
);

advanced['houseAge'] = $('#houseAge').val();
advanced['living_area'] = $('#living_area').val();
//advanced['lotsize'] = '';

// store data in array to post to server
vals = {
    advanced: advanced
};

$.post(
   "<?php echo $this->url->get('/ajax/session/update');?>",
   {values: vals}
);
```

The session file data was created by:

```
$this->session->set('advancedSearchCriteria', json_encode($values['advanced']));
```

So while I understand from the comments the "arrays" shown above are "NOT JSON" I can only ask, "How is that?" What is so wrong with the code above?

Thank you for your thoughts.

**ANSWER**
In the comments below others stated this was not valid JSON. As shown in the examples above it is JSON created by jQuery regardless if valid or not.

With the comments from Barmar I found the stringify command used above was not in the proper place. Updated code follows and works.

```
if (found) {
   advanced[id] = arrCB; //JSON.stringify(arrCB);
   i = 1;
   arrCB = {}; // zero out holders
}
```

and in the vals array:

```
vals = {
   advanced: JSON.stringify(advanced)
};
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because you didn't load jQuery. That's why it says `$` is not defined.

Comment: or an array, or a multidimensional array

Comment: In the fiddle you assign the variable `criteria`, then you use `JSON.parse(result)`, but you never set `result`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g65wj1e7/4/ I did not know when you "update" a session it increments the URL. Lesson learned.

Comment: @Barmar - I will have to try to figure out why jQuery and PHP don't know how to create json arrays. Meanwhile it seems I will have to find another way than Javascript to handle all this. Looks like Javascript and jQuery are not capable of handling data properly.

Comment: @Steven Javascript and jQuery have no problem creating JSON. The problem is almost certainly in your code. If you post the code maybe we can help you.

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` on a Javascript array or object and it will create correct JSON. In PHP, use `json_encode()`.